# Count columns performance issues

Tags: shell, awk

I have a `.csv` file with 130,000 lines. I want to read all lines from this file and check if the number of columns is less than 17, then append `|0` at the end of the line.

First I calculated the number of columns, but only by doing this the running time increased from 10 seconds to almost 3 minutes.

This is what I've tried:

```
while read line;
do
    nr_columns=$(echo $line | awk -F'|' '{print NF}')
    echo $line>> out
done<input_file.csv
```

I've tried also with `tr`, but the running time is also increased.

How can I do this faster?

Thank you all. This is what i've done:

```
awk -v separator=$sep -v nr_fields=$header_col -F '$sep' '{ if (NF  < nr_fields) print $0separator0;else print $0}' input_file.csv > outputfile
```

Comment: This is a good example of what this question is about: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Comment: You should add examples of what your input file looks like and what you expect the output to be. You say it's a `.csv` file, but you want to append `|0` - is it really comma separated, or pipe separated?

Comment: It seems like `awk -F '|' 'NF<17{$0=$0"|0"}1' input_file.csv > out` could solve your problem, but it's hard to tell without example input and expected output.

Comment: If you know all the lines have the same number of columns, you could try just checking the first line with `nr_columns=$(head -1 input_file.csv | awk -F'|' '{print NF}')`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it much faster by recognizing that `awk` is not just for one-liners--it is a real programming language.  Put this in a file `foo.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    OFS="|"
}
NF < 17 {
    print $0,"0"
}
NF >= 17 {
    print
}
```

Then run it like `awk -F'|' -f foo.awk input_file.csv`.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like all you need is:

```
awk -F'|' '{print $0 (NF<17 ? FS 0 : "")}' input_file.csv
```

but it's just a guess without concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but this is definitely efficient.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! $(head -1 input_file.csv | awk -F'|' '{print NF}') -eq 17 ]; then
  echo "input_file.csv does not have 17 columns"
  exit 2
fi

sed 's/$/\|0/g' input_file.csv > out
```

First, we check that the number of columns is indeed 17.  If not, we send a message and exit.  If we are good, we proceed to add the `|0` to the lines.

Comment: No, it's still extremely inefficient and it's buggy. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @EdMorton You are right.  Was trying to keep the same format he was using while removing the calculation from the loop. Edited...

Comment: FYI `$(head -1 input_file.csv | awk -F'|' '{print NF}') -eq 17` can be written as just one command `awk -F'|' 'NR==1{exit (NF==17)}' input_file.csv`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're really saying "if a record has less than 17 fields, I know it has 16 fields", then I'd append however many new fields to get to 17:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} NF < 17 {for (i=NF+1; i<=17; i++) $i=0} 1' <<END
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q
END
```

```
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|0|0|0
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q
```

Some reasons why your approach is so slow:

1. bash is slow
2. bash `read` command is REALLY slow: it reads one byte at a time
3. you invoke `awk` once per line